# Estimation of delay in digital circuit

Tags: digital-logic, inverter, load, delay, interconnect

[image]

I found this way to compute the High-to-Low propagation delay. How would this model be modified if instead of Having only a Cload after the transistor, there is a L-shaped RC segment (a low-pass first order filter) as a load? I mean there is an extra resistor R_L right below the arrow where ID is flowing, between Drain and Vout, as in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome: can I suggest you add a diagram of the exact circuit you're asking about?  It really helps clarify your question, and you can simulate it right away.

Comment: I edited the question. The circuit is the same, just with a resistor before CL. I would like to know how to model the high to low delay in this case, with an RC load instead of a simple C load.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Estimation of RC delay in digital circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/672979/estimation-of-rc-delay-in-digital-circuit)

Comment: I dislike that the site automatically adds the "did this answer your question" comment when duplicates or near-duplicates are found. Because your previous question uses almost the same title, please consider editing so they are more obviously distinct, if in fact they are not duplicates.

Comment: @JYelton If you refresh the page after voting for closure because of a duplicate, you will see the comment automatically generated in your name, hover over it, and you can either edit or delete it to your liking. ;-) I sometimes do any of this.